# What happened to Yisro?

Tags: history, tanach

What happened to Yisro after he went back to Midyan to convert his family?
שמות 18:27
Also, is he mentioned anywhere after in tanach?
(him, not his descendants)

Comment: A quick search of Tanakh will show you the word Yitro isn't mentioned again in Tanakh

Comment: But his other names are

Comment: @Shlomy Perhaps, if he had other names. Same for everyone else in Tanakh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He obviously returned to the Midbar later on because he is mentioned again in BaMidbar (Numbers) 10:29
וַיֹּ֣אמֶר משֶׁ֗ה לְ֠חֹבָ֠ב בֶּן־רְעוּאֵ֣ל הַמִּדְיָנִי֘ חֹתֵ֣ן משֶׁה֒
נֹֽסְעִ֣ים אֲנַ֗חְנוּ אֶל־הַמָּקוֹם֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר אָמַ֣ר 'ה

*Moses said to Chovov the son of Reuel the Midianite, Moses's father-in-law, We are traveling to the place about which Hashem said*

The Pesukim continue with  Yisro saying that he want to return to  Midyan. Moshe asks him to remain with them in them in the Midbar . The Ramban(ibid) based on the Yerushalmai in Bikkurim says that he stayed with them and went with them to Eretz Yisroel.

In Shoftim 1:16 there is a reference to his descendants living with the Jews in Eretz Yisroel

Comment: He asked about Yisro and you answered with a verse about Chovav. What in the world is "obvious" here?

Comment: Because "Chovov the son of Reuel the Midianite, Moses's father-in-law", is obviously Yisro

Comment: And I'm obviously Donald Trump...

Comment: Is Reuel Moshe's father in law? Or is Reuel's son Chovav the father in law? How many fathers in law did Moshe have?  I can say pretty objectively none of those answers are obvious, so please also include how you know. Plus this is Judaism so surely all those answers are subject to machloket

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different opinions. In the pesukim, it says ויחד which Rashi interprets as he left to Midyan, converted them to Judaism, and I guess lived out the rest of his days there.
Next, there’s actually an argument over what happened first; Matan Torah or the story of Yisro. I won’t outline all the arguments, but basically according to Ramban I believe, Yisro came after Milchemet Amalek to Bnei Yisroel and then went with them to Har Sinai to experience Matan Torah with them and help them understand the Torah.